# dirty degraded array, unable superblock, kernel panic

Tags: raid5, kernel-panic

Machine: linux centos 5.4 with 2 hdds and raid 5 (yes, 3rd disk missing).

Situation:

1. all running fine (3rd disk missing)
2. then a power off (system shut down itself when battery power ended).
3. machine not coming back

message on screen:

```
Memory for crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) notwithin permissible range
PCI: BIOS Bug: MCFC area at e0000000 is not E820-reserved
PCI: Not using MMCONFIG.
Red Hat nash version 5.1.19.6 starting
insmod: error inserting '/lib/raid456.ko': -1 File exists
md: md2: raid array is not clean -- starting background reconstruction
raid5: cannot start dirty degraded array for md2
raid5: failed to run raid set md2
md: pers->run() failed ...
md: md2: raid array is not clean -- starting background reconstruction
raid5: cannot start dirty degraded array for md2
raid5: failed to run raid set md2
md: pers->run() failed ...
EXT3-fs: unable to read superblock
mount: error mounting /dev/root on /sysroot as ext3: Invalid argument
setuproot: moving /dev failed: No such file or directory00
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory
setuproot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

so i installed sysresccd on memory stick and booted with it. 
then i run these tests:

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sda 
smartctl -X /dev/sda 
smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
```

and same with sdb. results are:

```
sda: test=Short offline, status="Completed without error", remaining=00%, lifetime=19230, firsterror=- 
sdb: test=Short offline, status="Completed: read failure", remaining=90%, lifetime=19256, firsterror=67031516
```

and the detail of sdb:

```
root@sysresccd /root % smartctl -A /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [i686-linux-3.0.21-std250-i586] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   180   180   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       5975
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       19256
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   183   183   000    Old_age   Always       -       51128
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   111   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       17
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

the Current_Pending_Sector 17 might be a problem.

then the further steps:
 1. bought 3x 2tb hdds
 2. booted with memory stick 
 3. copied the 2 old 1.5tb disks to 2 of the new ones one after another:
    dd if=/dev/sda of=dev/sdc bs=32M
    dd if=/dev/sdb of=dev/sdc bs=32M
 4. removed the 2 old disks (to not make matters worse)
 5. attached the 3 new disks. rebooted.

the output then goes like this:

```
Memory for crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) notwithin permissible range
PCI: BIOS Bug: MCFC area at e0000000 is not E820-reserved
PCI: Not using MMCONFIG.
Red Hat nash version 5.1.19.6 starting
insmod: error inserting '/lib/raid456.ko': -1 File exists
md: invalid raid superblock magic on sdb3
md: md2: raid array is not clean -- starting background reconstruction
raid5: not enough operational devices for md2 (2/3 failed)
raid5: failed to run raid set md2
md: pers->run() failed ...
md: md2: raid array is not clean -- starting background reconstruction
raid5: not enough operational devices for md2 (2/3 failed)
raid5: failed to run raid set md2
md: pers->run() failed ...
EXT3-fs: unable to read superblock
mount: error mounting /dev/root on /sysroot as ext3: Invalid argument
setuproot: moving /dev failed: No such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /sys: No such file or directory
setuproot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

so i booted with the new disks and sysresccd from memory stick. here is some information:

```
fdisk -l
shows the two full disks exactly like the output was on the old disks

Device  Boot    Start   End Blocks  Id  System
/dev/sda1   *   63  610469  305203+ fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       610470  8803619 4096575 fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       8803620 2930272064  1460734222+ fd  Linux raid autodetect

/dev/sdb1   *   63  610469  305203+ fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       610470  8803619 4096575 fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       8803620 2930272064  1460734222+ fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

sdc doens't contain a valid partition table (that's the empty 3rd disk)

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sda
smartctl -X /dev/sda
smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
sda: test=Short offline, status="Completed without error", remaining=00%, lifetime=19230, firsterror=-
sdb: test=Short offline, status="Completed: read failure", remaining=90%, lifetime=19256, firsterror=67031516

smartctl -A /dev/sdb
offline_uncorrectable: 0
```

then:

```
root@sysresccd /root % cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md125 : inactive sda3[0](S)
      1460734144 blocks

md126 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      305088 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md127 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      4096448 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

note: the raid5 is shown as md125 there.

detail for 127:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sun Dec 13 18:45:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 4096448 (3.91 GiB 4.19 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4096448 (3.91 GiB 4.19 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 127
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Mar  8 00:40:45 2012
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 939f1a92:590d4172:2414ef47:5e2b15cb
         Events : 0.236

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
```

for 126:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sun Dec 13 19:21:09 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 305088 (297.99 MiB 312.41 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 305088 (297.99 MiB 312.41 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 126
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Mar  7 23:34:02 2012
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : bde56644:86d3e3a4:1128f4fe:0f47f21f
         Events : 0.242

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

detail for 125:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --detail /dev/md125
mdadm: md device /dev/md125 does not appear to be active.
```

sda3:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --examine /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 062f3190:b9337fc1:0b38f5df:7ec7c53b
  Creation Time : Sun Dec 13 18:45:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1460733952 (1393.06 GiB 1495.79 GB)
     Array Size : 2921467904 (2786.13 GiB 2991.58 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2

    Update Time : Sat Mar  3 22:48:34 2012
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : e5ac0d6c - correct
         Events : 26243911

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 256K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3

   0     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
```

sdb3:
    root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --examine /dev/sdb3
    mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb3.

then:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --examine /dev/sd[ab]3 | egrep 'dev|Update|Role|State|Chunk Size'
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb3.
/dev/sda3:
    Update Time : Sat Mar  3 22:48:34 2012
          State : active
     Chunk Size : 256K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   0     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
```

more:

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --verbose --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md2 level=raid5 num-devices=3 UUID=062f3190:b9337fc1:0b38f5df:7ec7c53b
   devices=/dev/sda3
ARRAY /dev/md126 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=bde56644:86d3e3a4:1128f4fe:0f47f21f
   devices=/dev/sdb1,/dev/sda1
ARRAY /dev/md127 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=939f1a92:590d4172:2414ef47:5e2b15cb
   devices=/dev/sdb2,/dev/sda2
```

(note: here it's listed as md125 and not md2)

```
root@sysresccd /root % mdadm --verbose --create --assume-clean /dev/md2 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3 missing
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sda3: Device or resource busy
mdadm: failed container membership check
mdadm: device /dev/sda3 not suitable for any style of array
```

UPDATE:
it could be that the dd copy of disk sdb did not succeed. the copy of sdb looked suspicious, and so i run this:

```
root@sysresccd /root % dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/sdc3 bs=128M
11144+1 records in
11144+1 records out
1495791843840 bytes (1.5 TB) copied, 42354.9 s, 35.3 MB/s
root@sysresccd /root % dd if=/dev/sdb3 of=/dev/sdd3 bs=128M
dd: reading `/dev/sdb3': Input/output error
222+1 records in
222+1 records out
29813932032 bytes (30 GB) copied, 676.459 s, 44.1 MB/s
root@sysresccd /root %
```

this time only copying the sdb3 partition since sdb1 and sdb2 were fine. 
as you can see it aborts. thus i am now running:

ddrescue -S -c 20480 -f /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdd3 /tmp/log3

to copy it again, this time with ddrescue. it will take many more hours, so far there were errsize=17928 kB and errors=3.

i'll update this post when the copy finishes and i find out more.

Comment: What are the model numbers of the disks?  Some disks aren't really RAID suitable (WD Blues and WD Greens to name a pair.)

Comment: the old ones are wd caviar greens (was working fine for 2 years)

Comment: Do they pass SMART (short and extended) tests?

Comment: new disks: seagate barracuda green (adv. format), device model ST2000DL003-9VT166, has smart capability

Comment: old disks: wd caviar gren, device model = WDC WD5EADS-00P8B0, has smart capability. will check smart tests now.

Comment: smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl -s /dev/sda 
smartctl -H /dev/sda = PASSED
same for sdb

Comment: I don't mean the passed or fail.  If you run `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` then wait a few mins, then run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` then riiiight at the bottom, there's a block on test results.

Comment: smartctl -t short /dev/sda
smartctl -X /dev/sda
smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
sda: test=Short offline, status="Completed without error", remaining=00%, lifetime=19230, firsterror=-
sdb: test=Short offline, status="Completed: read failure", remaining=90%, lifetime=19256, firsterror=67031516
i run the test on sdb twice, same result. will try now what you wrote, and then the smartctl -t long /dev/sdb

Comment: (long test will take 255 minutes)

Comment: result of smartctl -A /dev/sdb is http://no-paste.ch/show_521.html

Comment: the new disk (copied using dd) has Current_Pending_Error=0

Comment: the kernel panic i get when running with the new disks (dd copies): http://nopaste.info/fbaa5e8149.html

Comment: this website has issues. one is that i can't edit the original post unless i remove the image it contains (since i am a new user).

Comment: i updated the main post with the information from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

(answering myself)

ddrescue solved the problem, afterwards it was possible to re-assemble the raid5 array.